# Finite degree field extension is a simple extension iff there are only finitely many intermediate fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F\subset E$ be a finite degree field extension. Then $E=F[\alpha]$ for some element $\alpha \in E$ iff there are only finitely many fields $K$ with $F \subset K \subset E$. In other words, a finite degree field extension is a simple extension if and only if there are only finitely many intermediate fields.

I don't know how should begin the proof. Is there any book you can suggest to read this proof of theorem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Serge Lang's *Algebra*. It's the *Primitive element theorem*.

Comment: I want to see a motivation example. For instance, let $F[\alpha]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 6]$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$. Are the intermediate fields $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 3]$?

Comment: No. None of them is contained in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt 6]$. Actually, the latter has only two subfields, itself and $\mathbf Q$, since it is a degree $2$ extension of  $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Can you give a valid example?

Comment: A valid example of what?

Comment: I mean that I want to see an example like: The intermediate fields of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3]$ are $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2]$, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 3]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 6]$.

Comment: I don't see anything about finite fields so I removed the tag. $\Bbb{Q}$ and its extensions all have infinitely many elements.